# Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable when trying to create Sort methods

Tags: c#

I have created 3 methods:

```
public IOrderedEnumerable<JObject> SortByImportance(IOrderedEnumerable<JObject> products)
{
    if (products == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(products));

    var firstProduct = products.First();
    return !firstProduct.ContainsKey("importance") ? 
        products : 
        products.OrderByDescending(m => m["importance"]);
}

public async Task<IOrderedEnumerable<JObject>> SortByPriorityAsync(string categoryId, IOrderedEnumerable<JObject> products, List<Answer> answers)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryId)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(categoryId));
    if (products == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(products));
    if (answers == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(answers));

    var questions = await _questionProvider.Value.ListAsync(categoryId);
    if (questions == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(questions));
    if (questions.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(questions));

    foreach (var answer in answers)
        answer.Question = questions.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == answer.QuestionId);

    var sortedAnswers = answers.OrderBy(m => m.Question.Priority);
    return sortedAnswers.Aggregate(products, (current, answer) => current.ThenByDescending(m => m[answer.Question.Text.ToLower()].ToString().Equals(answer.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
}

public async Task<IOrderedEnumerable<JObject>> SortBySortationAsync(string categoryId, IOrderedEnumerable<JObject> products)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoryId)) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(categoryId));
    if (products == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(products));

    var sortations = await _sortationProvider.Value.ListAsync(categoryId);
    if (sortations == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(sortations));
    if (sortations.Count == 0) throw new ArgumentException(nameof(sortations));

    var orderedSortations = sortations.OrderBy(m => m.Order);

    return orderedSortations.Aggregate(products, (current, sortation) => current.ThenByDescending(m => m[sortation.Field].ToString().Equals(sortation.Expression)));
}
```

these three methods can be called in an order to change the order of a list of products.
An example might be this:

```
var orderedProducts = products.OrderBy(a => 1);
orderedProducts = await sortProvider.SortBySortationAsync(categoryId, orderedProducts);
orderedProducts = await sortProvider.SortByPriorityAsync(categoryId, orderedProducts, answers);
orderedProducts = sortProvider.SortByImportance(orderedProducts);
```

This works fine and my unit tests are showing that the sorting is fine, but inside the `SortByImportance` method, it is stating:

> Possible multiple enumeration of IEnumerable

on the `products.First()` invocation.
Can anyone tell me how I can resolve this?

Comment: You can convert your collection ToList() once and prevent this warning.

Comment: If I do that, I can't use my methods because they use `ThenBy` rather than `OrderBy` to maintain the previous order

Comment: "return firstProduct.ContainsKey("importance") ? 
        products.OrderByDescending(m => m["importance"]) : products;" is easier to read

Comment: this isn't really a "possible" multiple enumeration; you **are** enumerating it multiple times...

Answer (score 0):

If it is desirable behaviour, you can always suppress the warning with proper comment.

Or, you could do a trick:

```
var orderedProducts = products.OrderBy(a => 1) 
                       .ToList() // do the sorting
                       .OrderBy(a => 1); //convert to IOrderedEnumerable
```

The warning will still be there, but the second ordering will be optimal scenario for sorting, resulting in simply converting IEnumerable to IOrderedEnumerable (possibly with one enumeration).

Answer (score 0):

Try `var firstProduct = products.ToList().First();`